# How do I change the control type from a button to a togglebutton in Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls, expression-blend, blend

I've created quite a complex button, but I've now realized that it should've been a Toggle Button (due to needing the checked state).  Is it possible to simply change something in the code to make this happen?

I'd rather not have to start from scratch on a new toggle button

```
    <ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
<Style x:Key="HolonBaseButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="383*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MouseOver}"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="Background" Data="M0.5,0.5 L383.5,0.5 399.5,16.499999 399.5,59.5 0.5,59.5 z" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource HolonBaseBackground}"/>
                        </Path.Fill>
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource HolonBaseStroke}"/>
                        </Path.Stroke>
                    </Path>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="182.188,22.02,165.188,22.02"/>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnMark" Content="ToggleButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource MarkToggleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TimeCreated" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="Auto" Margin="0,3.7,20.794,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="9 mins ago" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontFamily="{DynamicResource SystemText}" FontSize="10" TextAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DisabledControlsText}"/>
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Selector" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="{x:Null}" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Selector}"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MarkToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid Width="17" Height="17">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="background">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="background">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="On">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="background" Data="M0.5,0.5 L38.308,0.5 38.308,38.308 z" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0" Width="17" Height="17">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MarkMouseover}"/>
                        </Path.Fill>
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF9C5E00"/>
                        </Path.Stroke>
                    </Path>
                    <Path x:Name="On" Data="M0.5,0.5 L38.308,0.5 38.308,38.308 z" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0" Visibility="Visible" Width="17" Height="17">
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MarkMouseover}"/>
                        </Path.Stroke>
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Mark}"/>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="17"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="17"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="17"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="17"/>
</Style>
<!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
```

Comment: search for `Button` and replace with `ToggleButton` in xaml? that would include find-replace in xaml `Style` definition including inside TypeDefinitions for Style and possibly `ControlTemplate` (`TargetType="{x:Type Button}"`) and usage areas(`<Button>`).

Comment: @viv hi viv, thanks, I did that, but I've now got an error that highlighted the following line:
<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>

Comment: what line is that? just post your code for the `Button` would make this faster

Comment: sorry, pressed enter. thanks, I did that, but I've now got an error that highlighted the following line: <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>

Comment: I deleted the line and it seems ok. but will this have any ramifications

Comment: switch `<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>` to `<Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">` and try. Yeh ofc it will have ramifications. That's an odd question don't you think. If you delete something that was there for a reason, you're gonna notice some issues.

Comment: Also, whats the TypeDefinitions for Style mean?

Comment: actually saying that what you've posted is an empty trigger so no you will not have ramifications cos it wasn't doing anything to begin with and should prolly have not been left there to begin-with

Comment: Sorry I thought it would've been something that was relevant to a Button control, and not to a ToggleButton, as you mentioned something similar in one of your other comments

Comment: `whats the TypeDefinitions for Style mean`. well what it literally means in english it's the type the Style / ControlTemplate is intended for as in the Target control's type which you had as Button and should now be ToggleButton

Comment: don't worry about it. Although I would suggest you pick up some basic tutorial's on WPF `Style`'s to get familiar with these concepts. They're kind of important to say the least and you'd appreciate a strong foundation later on.

Comment: I changed it, but it gave me another error.  I've deleted the line again - so if it's an empty trigger, that should be ok yeah?  Also, you should put this as the answer. I believe it is, then I can mark it.  One final thing viv, the TypeDefinitions for Style, should I change something here (all I did was find and replace button)?

Comment: lol ok I'll just summarize this into an answer(including what type-definitions is) but you rlllllllllly need to get a book on WPF and start brushing up with basics :)

Comment: yeah I'm going to get a book.  I was actually looking not to get too involved in coding (as I am far better at UI design), however it seems it'll give me a good foundation

Comment: viv, just added the code for the button (as it was before doing the find and replace)

Comment: ah that's great ill just edit that and post it :). Every UI designer would wanna get away from bland coding but to be good in one you definitely need a good understanding and appreciation of the other ;)

Comment: haha, but I don't think it's bland, it's just not the way my brain is wired up. I greatly appreciate what coders do, it amazes me, ask the guys here with me. but on the other hand, they don't have a clue about UI design and, likewise, avoid it.  I totally believe that people should specialize in what they're good at (which usually results in passion and aptitude), especially given the fact that technology and knowledge has increased and diversified to such an extent that no one person could ever hope to cover all fields.  Just look at science, an immense number of fields...

Comment: ... that one scientist could never understand. Just 100 years ago, a scientist could know all there was about science, but today, that's impossible.  What I'm saying is, people should specialize and focus on the skills they have to contribute to multi-disciplinary teams.  I would like to avoid code because it's not my wiring, the person who has that special skill should handle it (it's better for the project), i'll take care of the User Experience, that's my focus and passion.  A crack team of focused individuals, adding their skills and covering the areas others lack, making the whole better

Comment: While I agree with your idea, With WPF xaml coding is not really coding like c# or c++. We have people who do not use Visual Studio or Blend but do design aspects of UI. We refer to them as "Artists" not "Designers" and they work in Illustrator / Photoshop mainly and get wireframes given to "Designers". Now "Designers" work with this data and translate it into blend and mock it with sample data and sorts to get the UI feel to their requirements when the programmer's worry about the backend and app functionality.

Comment: My point is with "you can't be great in all" - Totally agree. However "you cant be great in any" - without a slight overlap between sections. It's not extensive but a mutual overlap so that when ppl communicate it's not greek n Latin between teams. It just helps that way cos Artists knw when they should prolly just breakup artboards in illustrator smaller or designers gonna have a hard time and when designers knw what can be done in a Style and xaml and what just needs code-behind and attached properties and DP's and sorts.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I agree that there needs to be some overlap, and I'm going to learn some WPF.  I would be on the artist side, and shouldn't really be doing blend so intensely (although I chose to in order to get that overlap), I'm fortunate in a sense that I already designed the whole UI, and am now building it, because I wouldn't have done a lot of aspects of this UI due to knowing how complex it is to build.  I believe that there should be separation, as 'not' knowing something can't be done or is too hard will push the others to find a way to do it (like I'm now pushing myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to start from scratch especially with it being a `Button` -> `ToggleButton` where they are almost identical in base functionality.

So by just doing a find and replace `Button` to `ToggleButton` you'd be almost done. As you mentioned `ToggleButton` does not like:

```
<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
```

so you need to switch that to

```
<Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
```

however if you look at that xaml, it's an empty `Trigger` definition which is pointless. So in your Style you could just get rid of the following bit:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
  <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
  <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Am not going to start explaining what makes this an empty `Trigger`, As I mentioned you should pick up a book on "Basic WPF and Blend" to get to grip with how to do stuff in blend and what blend actually does for you in the background.

As for `TypeDefinition`:

It just means what's the type of control, that `Style` / `ControlTemplate` is intended for.

In the following lines:

```
<Style x:Key="HolonBaseButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

the `TargetType="{x:Type Button}"` says that the Style in first line and `ControlTemplate` in second are intended to be used for a `Button` so if you try to use it for a `ToggleButton`, you'd get an error. It's pretty verbose, so to switch it you just switch `Button` with `ToggleBUtton` which the find and replace would do fine.

So your converted `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="HolonBaseButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="383*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MouseOver}"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="Background" Data="M0.5,0.5 L383.5,0.5 399.5,16.499999 399.5,59.5 0.5,59.5 z" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource HolonBaseBackground}"/>
                        </Path.Fill>
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource HolonBaseStroke}"/>
                        </Path.Stroke>
                    </Path>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="182.188,22.02,165.188,22.02"/>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnMark" Content="ToggleButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource MarkToggleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TimeCreated" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="Auto" Margin="0,3.7,20.794,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="9 mins ago" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontFamily="{DynamicResource SystemText}" FontSize="10" TextAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DisabledControlsText}"/>
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Selector" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="{x:Null}" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Selector}"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I copied n pasted your code above, but what happened was that there is a togglebutton in the button and that got changed to some kind of default look.  You probably didn't see that there was another togglebutton, I should've said.  But in any case, I just did the find and replace.  I also kept the triggers in there, but changed what you said, just in case I needed them in the future and it gave me errors.  So once again, thanks viv, it works and u saved me a lot of grief

Comment: hi viv, would you mind answering my new question, regarding the overlap showing.  I can't figure it out